# How to prevent the core/group block from being ungrouped?

Tags: block-editor

I use a core/group block in a block pattern that I want users to be able to insert anywhere in a post. I'm locking down as much of the layout of this pattern and the internal blocks as possible.

How can I prevent editors from being able to group/ungroup the group block in the pattern?

I would like the following options removed from this menu:

[image]